# What is the best way to share configs between backend and frontend?

Tags: node.js, git, ember.js, configuration

I have backend built with `Express.js` and frontend built with `Ember.js`. In my git repo there are two folders with frontend and backend. I have file with constants on backend but I don't want to duplicate this file in the frontend.

Also, I could make a request from frontend to the backend to get these constants and further work with it from `Ember.DS` but I don't want a redundant query to API.

I think best way to make module and add it into requirements on backend and on frontend. But for this, I need to create a separate repo and I think it's overhead to use 2 repositories.

Please recommend another good way to solve this problem.

Comment: How often is the config going to be changed? If its not very often, I would just accept that you need to change it in two places. Like you said, having it in a separate repo is probably over kill. Creating an API endpoint is probably more overkill.

Comment: I have a similar layout and also use Express.js with Ember.js. My folder structure has the API server as a subfolder inside the Ember app though - and using that structure you could import the config using something like import Config from '../apiserver/config/conf.json'. I've also found having ember in the TLD of a repo makes it significantly easier for me to deploy